Trouble with powershell script for log extract
Hi im current new to powershell and playing with the below script.
My end goal is to scan multiply 'Log.txt' for the string :
TOTAL NUMBER OF MAILS SUCCESSFULY PROCESSED FOR USER [ Admin.Task@hiscox.com ]

and then output the results of the string and other text on the same line into a text file which i need to send out.
Can someone please tell me where im going wrong its fails on every attempt even though there is text ther, Forexample the line would show:
TOTAL NUMBER OF MAILS SUCCESSFULY PROCESSED FOR USER [ Admin.Task@hiscox.com ] [55] 

Thanks
Paul
*# Define the log file path
$logFilePath = "H:\Playground\PowerShell\All\Logs\All*.log"
*# Define the string to search for
$SearchString = "*TOTAL NUMBER OF MAILS SUCCESSFULY PROCESSED FOR USER [ Admin.Task@hiscox.com ]*"
*# Perform the search in the log file
$result = Get-Content -Path $logFilePath | Select-String -Pattern $searchString
*# Define the output file path
$outputFilePath = "H:\Playground\PowerShell\AcquireAll\Results\Res.txt"
Send-MailMessage -To "Paul.Ballard@mymail.com" -From "Paul.Ballard@mymail.com" -Subject "test" -Body "See attached" -Attachments "H:\Playground\PowerShell\AcquireAll\Results\Res.txt"  -SmtpServer "mymail.server.com"**


-Pattern needs regex.  Perhaps something similar to this is what you want: https://regex101.com/r/aaTF37/1

You have an invalid regular expression in your $SearchString string, your script should actually be failing with the error:

The string *TOTAL NUMBER OF MAILS SUCCESSFULY PROCESSED FOR USER [ Admin.Task@hiscox.com ]* is not a valid regular expression: Invalid pattern '*TOTAL NUMBER OF MAILS SUCCESSFULY PROCESSED FOR USER [ Admin.Task@hiscox.com ]*' at offset 1.
Quantifier '*' following nothing.

If you're looking for lines that match exactly:
TOTAL NUMBER OF MAILS SUCCESSFULY PROCESSED FOR USER [ Admin.Task@hiscox.com ]

Followed by or preceded by anything else you can use -SimpleMatch and in the pattern you put the literal string to match. You can also use Select-String to read files, no need for Get-Content. It also seems you wanted to store the results in a file but never did that so, you can add Set-Content after.
$logFilePath = 'H:\Playground\PowerShell\All\Logs\All*.log'
# Define the string to search for
$SearchString = 'TOTAL NUMBER OF MAILS SUCCESSFULY PROCESSED FOR USER [ Admin.Task@hiscox.com ]'
# Define the output file path
$outputFilePath = 'H:\Playground\PowerShell\AcquireAll\Results\Res.txt'
# Perform the search in the log file
Select-String -Path $logFilePath -Pattern $searchString -SimpleMatch |
    # and save the results here
    Set-Content $outputFilePath

$sendMailMessageSplat = @{
    To          = 'Paul.Ballard@mymail.com'
    From        = 'Paul.Ballard@mymail.com'
    Subject     = 'test'
    Body        = 'See attached'
    Attachments = 'H:\Playground\PowerShell\AcquireAll\Results\Res.txt'
    SmtpServer  = 'mymail.server.com'
}

Send-MailMessage @sendMailMessageSplat

